# Cypher - Combine 2 queries evaluate which where clause is true

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is my query:

```
MATCH (u:User {userId:'aUser'})-[:REL_1]->(n2:Node2)-[:REL_2]->(n3:Node3)-[:REL_3]->(n4_1:Node4)-[:REL_4*]->(n4_2:Node4) 
    WHERE  n4_2.property='Green' 

MATCH (u:User {userId:'aUser'})-[:REL_1]->(n2:Node2)-[:REL_2]->(n3:Node3)-[:REL_3]->(n4_1:Node4) 
    WHERE n4_1.property='Green'
```

I want to combine those 2 queries. What I am trying to achieve is RETURN n4_2 if the upper where is correct, n4_1 if the lower where is correct, return `null` if no MATCH is found at all. A union is not the case here, cause columns don't have the same names.

Comment: Do you want to return 'n4_2' or value of field n4_2?

Comment: Union can be used if you return it as same name in both queries.

Comment: i want to return the whole n4_2 node or n4_1 node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **UNION** in this case.

```
MATCH (u:User {userId:'aUser'})-[:REL_1]->(n2:Node2)-[:REL_2]->(n3:Node3)-[:REL_3]->(n4_1:Node4)-[:REL_4*]->(n4_2:Node4) 
WHERE  n4_2.property='Green' 
RETURN n4_2 AS node
UNION ALL 
MATCH (u:User {userId:'aUser'})-[:REL_1]->(n2:Node2)-[:REL_2]->(n3:Node3)-[:REL_3]->(n4_1:Node4) 
WHERE n4_1.property='Green'
RETURN n4_1 AS node
```

In your case, **n4_2**  and **n4_1** both are of same Node type (i.e. Node4).

**Union** also works even if types of nodes are different like one is Person and other is Movie, Like:

```
MATCH (n1:Person) WHERE n1.born=1961 RETURN  n1 as node
UNION ALL 
MATCH (n2:Person) WHERE n2.born=1967 RETURN  n2 as node
UNION ALL 
MATCH (m1:Movie) WHERE m1.released=2006 RETURN  m1 as node
```